# Python Requests timeout parameter is being ignored

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, python-requests

I'm using Python 2.7, I want every request to timeout after some seconds, but the requests timeout almost immediately. Following is my code.

```
requestsTimeout = 5
link = 'http://' + IP + '/api/v1.0/system/info'
while (1):
    try:
        return requests.get(link, timeout = requestsTimeout)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        log._print0(_printID, 'getting DAQ Info' ,str(e)) # just printing
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Now if I disconnect my wifi, I should get a printout of timeout exception after every 5 seconds, but I'm getting prints at a very fast rate (multiple times in one second).

Comment: `while True` over `while (1)`.

Comment: I switch between C and python on daily basis, and it gets really annoying handling different syntaxes, especially when you have to write 'True' instead of 'true' !

Comment: Is it really a Timeout exception you're getting? I would assume if you disconnect the wifi another exception would occur.

Comment: As stated by Reductio, you should be getting a different error, I think that would be a ConnectionError

Comment: You could use just the bare `Exception` instead of `requests.exceptions.RequestException` which includes all exceptions which also includes `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When host is unreachable `ConnectionError` is raised without waiting time set by `timeout`. You could overcome this by handling this exception separately:

```
requestsTimeout = 5
link = 'http://' + IP + '/api/v1.0/system/info'
while True:
    try:
        return requests.get(link, timeout=requestsTimeout)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        time.sleep(requestsTimeout)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        log._print0(_printID, 'getting DAQ Info' ,str(e)) # just printing
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: yes, it is indeed the connection error and not the timeout error,